# How to delete python3 from /usr/bin/ on MacOS Ventura?

Tags: python, macos-ventura

I want to remove `python3` from `/usr/bin`, as I already have Python 3.11 installed and the `python3` in `/usr/bin/` is Python 3.9.6

I tried removing it using `sudo rm -f python3`, but I get this error:
`rm: python3: Operation not permitted`

So, how?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should think thrice before attempting this. In your case, you can simply use the `python` version in `/usr/local/bin` by manipulating the `$PATH` variable. Homebrew probably does this automatically, you can try `which python` to find out what's the default on your system.

If you really, really want to do this, you can follow the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440334/sip-is-disabled-but-usr-bin-is-write-protected-anyway-macos-catalina-beta-10/59395264#59395264

Answer (score 0):

Modify PATH in ~/.zprofile like so:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Open a new Terminal session.

Most tools, like Visual Studio Code, will be able to detect all Python installations and let you choose.

This way you also can handle Python installed in /Library/Framework and Xcode, without going around and deleting.

**/usr/bin** is handled by the macOS and is protected by SIP (System Integrity Protection), which can be disabled, but why bother.